# Is $(|x_n|^{n+1})$ convergent or bounded if $|x_n|<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $|x_n|<1$. Is $(|x_n|^{n+1})$ convergent or bounded?

Comment: It is certainly bounded, since $|x_n|^{n+1}<1^{n+1}=1$.

Comment: And it's not necessarily convergent.  Can you find an example which doesn't converge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clearly bounded:
$$ |x_n|^{n+1} < 1^{n+1} = 1 \ . $$

It is not necessarily convergent. For example, take:
$$ x_n = \begin{cases} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} & \mbox{ if  } n=2k \ , \\ \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} & \mbox{ if  } n=2k+1 \ . \end{cases} $$

Comment: Is the example true ?

Comment: or take $(x_n)=(-1)^n$

Comment: @rlartiga : I think that in your example, $(\vert x_{n} \vert^{n+1})_{n \geq 0}$ is a convergent sequence !

Comment: @andii : $x_{n}=(-1)^{n}$ does not satisfy $\vert x_{n} \vert < 1$.

Comment: @jibounet my mistake the example of the answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: @jibounet you are right. just take $x_n=-1.$

Comment: @andii : $x_{n}=-1$ still doesn't work because it does not satisfy $\vert x_{n} \vert < 1$ (here : $\vert x_{n} \vert = 1$)

Comment: @jibounet ok. i think given example by LinAlgMan is quite good.